# typecover not working in wnidows, but works in UEFI

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I have a surface pro 4 running Wndows 10 Pro updated with latest updates and my type cover has recently stopped working.
It does work if I boot to the UEFI screen, but if I boot fully into windows, it doesn't respond.  I'm hoping it is a driver conflict or something similar, but am not sure how to track that down.

I've followed all troubleshooting instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023473/surface-troubleshoot-your-surface-type-cover-or-keyboard) that I can find short of resetting my machine as I don't want to have to reinstall all of my software.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can troubleshoot this?